# Angular Http get not doing api call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following:

country.service.ts

```
  getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    //const response = await fetch("http://10.0.0.197:8000/api/maps/countries/");
    //return await response.json();
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(
      "http://10.0.0.197:8000/api/maps/countries/"
    );
```

and

countries.component.ts

```
  getCountries(): void {
    // this.countryService
    //   .getCountries()
    //   .then((countries) => (this.countries = countries));
    this.countryService
      .getCountries()
      .subscribe((countries) => (this.countries = countries));
  }
```

However, I keep getting the error

[image]

Even though the endpoint is up and running. It was working with fetch. Do I need to change something?

Comment: That error is not caused by angular itself. Something with your url is likely wrong. Try to remove the last `/` for example

Comment: Sorry, it was using the InMemoryApiModule which upon reading the docs redirects all requests to said Module

Answer (score 0):

For any future users whom might run into this:

The issue was

```
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {
      dataEncapsulation: false,
    }),
```

in `app.module.ts imports[]`

Once I removed it, it worked